# how to get retina-ready?

Tags: html, css, retina-display

what do I have to do to make my web apps/sites retina-ready (on iPhone4 & iPad3) when it comes to

- videos
- images
- fonts
- colors ?

I'm looking for a checklist here.

Comment: 1. Buy The New iPad
2. Load App or web page in Safari on The New iPad
3. Analyze...

What I'm getting at, is without the device, it's really hard to test.

Comment: one must google about it instead of asking.. there are countless blog posts on the matter... nothing to add here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Rails 3.1+, you can use my [clear_eyes gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/clear_eyes) to automatically handle retina images.

Colors and fonts won't need any adjustments. For example, a CSS button will not require any adjustment, only images and perhaps video.

[Here's a very good flowchart](http://mir.aculo.us/2012/06/26/flowchart-how-to-retinafy-your-website/) of the steps required to completely retina-fy your site, although I recommend using the gem for images, if you're on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

[Smashing Magazine: Towards A Retina Web](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/) (mostly about graphics)

Answer (score 0):

for image:

```
<script>if(window.devicePixelRatio>1)document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="retina.png"</script>
```

for backgrounds:

```
<style>
  @media screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1), 
    screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
    screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){

      h1{background-image:url(retina.png)}

  }
</style>
```