# Retina Images not being loaded on sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, retina.js

I've included retina.js in my Sencha Touch application. When watching the network monitor I see

- retina.js is loaded
- images are loaded normaly `example.jpg`
- no @2x images are loaded `example@2x.jpg` or even looked for

Using [chrome to emulate an iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20240329/81785) this is all I see
[image: console]

I also manually ran `Retina.init(window)` however nothing happens. All images remain non-retina. Running `Retina.isRetina()` returns **true**

I don't actually own a retina device, so I am not sure if that is the issue. However my friend with an iPhone 5s says the image quality has not improved, so I am assuming the retina images are not showing up.

The [documentation is not very helpful](http://retinajs.com/#how-it-works)

I figure this has to do with the fact that images are created and loaded with JS (the images are not there onload)

Using chrome for debugging, how can I make retina.js work for my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I used a small part of the `retina.js` file and created a new class, it uses the isRetina function to tell weather the devicePixelRatio is higher than 1.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Retina', {
  singleton: true,
  isRetina : function(){
    var mediaQuery = "(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
                      (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),\
                      (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),\
                      (min-resolution: 1.5dppx)";

    if (window.devicePixelRatio > 1)
      return true;

    if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches)
      return true;

    return false;
  },
  getSrc: function(url){
    return this.isRetina()? [url.slice(0, -4), '@2x', url.slice(-4)].join(''): url;
  }
});
```

Now throughout my sencha app I create images with `MyApp.Retina.('http://example.com/foo.jpg')` as src value, when the device is retina the function returns `http://example.com/foo@2x.jpg`