# How to target iphone 11 landscape only with media queries

Tags: css

I want to target iphone 11/X landscape with media queries but its just not working for me? I am trying:

```
  @media screen and (max-device-width: 896px) and (orientation : landscape)   {
    .bstick {
      top: 200px!important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the iPhone 11 / 11 Pro / 11 Pro Max media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087446/what-are-the-iphone-11-11-pro-11-pro-max-media-queries)

Comment: No I have tried them

Comment: Would save others some time and effort by posting which ones you tried and didn't work?

Comment: The above I have tried and the ones in the link you sent