# Media queries not working at all on iPhone

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a iPhone 11 and try to reach my site https://tryggarehem.se/, I have specified meta tags relevant for using media queries. However, it seems not to work at all. I am totally lost here, this is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
    ...
</head>
```

CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) and (min-width: 751px) {
  .main-content {
    margin-top: -200px !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  .main-content {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iPhones are non-standard in their handling of CSS pixels vs device pixels. It might be possible your screen width is different than what you are assuming. You can fetch current screen width and check whether it lies within your applied range.

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var x = document.getElementById("data");
x.innerHTML = "Browser width: " + w + ", height: " + h + ".";
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="data"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can also try to use standard media queries for iPhones mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087446/all-media-queries-for-iphone-12-pro-max-mini-and-older-iphones)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.
What worked for me

```
Instead of 
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)

I used 
@media screen and (min-device-width: 600px)
```

Reason is

> All you are essentially interested in is the width of the viewport no matter the device. However the main difference between width and device-width is that device-widths don't always match the layout viewport of said device. Many tablets and mobile devices don't always have 1 device pixel per CSS pixel.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).