# Why do my breakpoints work if I scale down the window but not on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I created an online shop and used Media query breakpoints to adjust the content based on the screen width. Everything works fine if I change the screen size by changing the size of the browser. At the set breakpoint, my navbar collapses and everything looks great. But as soon as I switch to Mobile view things get weird. Somehow no matter how small I make the window, the navbar remains as it is. I have heard that the Chrome Dev tools are unreliable and can cause issues with responsiveness so I connected to my website with my iPhone 12 and the result stays the same, no responsiveness whatsoever.

[Here you can see the Navbar when viewed from the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFoSJ.jpg)

[This is the navbar how it's supposed to look after it colapses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX62D.png)

[This is how the navbar looks in Chrome dev tools as well as on my iPhone 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fW22.png)

This is my Navbar jsx

```
return (
    <>  
        <nav className={classes.navbar}>
            <Link to='/' className={classes.navbarLogo} > 
            FIRM
            </Link>
            <div className={classes.menuIcon} onClick={handleClick}>
                {click ? 
                <i><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} className={classes.fat}/></i> 
                : 
                <i><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} className={classes.fat}/></i>}
            </div>
            <ul className={click ? classes.navMenuActive : classes.navMenu}>
                <li className={classes.navItem}>
                    <Link to='/' className={classes.navbarLinks} onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Home
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={classes.navItem}
                    onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
                    onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
                >
                    <Link to='/Produkte' className={classes.navbarLinks} onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Produkte <i className='fas fa-caret-down'/>
                    </Link>
                    {dropdown && <Dropdown />}
                </li>
                <li className={classes.navItem}>
                    <Link to='/Kontakt' className={classes.navbarLinks} onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        Kontaktiere uns
                    </Link>
                </li>
                <li className={classes.navItem}>
                    <Link to='/Warenkorb' className={classes.navbarLinksMobile} onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                        <ShoppingCartIcon totalitems={totalitems}></ShoppingCartIcon>
                    </Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <NavButton className={classes.buttonFlex} totalitems={totalitems}/>
        </nav>
        <div className={classes.navBlock}></div>
    </>
    
)
```

}

These are my styles

```
export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
    navbar: {
        background: 'linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%)',
        height: '80px',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        fontSize: '1.2rem',
        width: "100%",
        position: "fixed"
    },
    navbarLogo: {
        color: '#fff',
        justifySelf: 'start',
        marginLeft: '20px',
        cursor: 'pointer',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        fontSize: '2rem',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans, sans-serif'
    },
    navMenu: {
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(5, auto)',
        gridGap: '10px',
        listStyle: 'none',
        textAlign: 'center',
        width: '70vw',
        justifyContent: 'end',
        marginRight: '2rem'
    },
    navItem: {
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        height: '80px',
    },
    navbarLinks: {
        color: 'white',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans, sans-serif',
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: '#1888ff',
            borderRadius: '4px',
            transition: 'all 0.2s ease-out'
        }
    },
    fat: {
        color: 'white'
    },
    navbarLinksMobile: {
        display: 'none'
    },
    menuIcon: {
        display: 'none',
    },
    navBlock : {
        height: "80px"
    },
    ['@media screen and (max-width: 960px)']: {
        NavbarItems: {
            position: 'relative'
        },
        navMenu: {
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            width: '100%',
            height: '90vh',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '80px',
            left: '-120%',
            opacity: '1',
            transition: 'all 0.5s ease',
            zIndex: '1',
        },
        navMenuActive: {
            paddingLeft: '0',
            marginTop: '0',
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            width: '100%',
            height: '90vh',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '80px',
            transition: 'all 0.5s ease',
            zIndex: '1',
            background: '#242222',
            left: '0',
            opacity: '1',
        },
        navbarLinks: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            padding: '2rem',
            width: '100%',
            display: 'table',
            '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: '#1888ff',
                borderRadius: '0'
            }
        },
        navbarLogo: {
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '0',
            left: '0',
            transform: 'translate(25%, 50%)'
        },
        menuIcon: {
            display: 'block',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '0',
            right: '0',
            transform: 'translate(-100%, 60%)',
            fontSize: '1.8rem',
            cursor: 'pointer'

        },
        '.fa-times': {
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: '2rem'
        },
        navbarLinksMobile: {
            display: 'block',
            textAlign: 'center',
            padding: '1.5rem',
            margin: '2rem auto',
            borderRadius: '4px',
            width: '80%',
            background: '#1888ff',
            textDecoration: 'none',
            color: '#fff',
            fontSize: '1.5rem',
            '&:hover': {
                backgroundColor: '#fff',
                color: '#1888ff',
                transition: '250ms',
            }
        },
        buttonFlex: {
            display: 'none'
        }
    }

}));
```

Comment: May you double-check the CSS that is being generated?

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087446/all-media-queries-for-iphone-13-pro-max-mini-and-older-iphones. Smartphones with sharper screens have higher pixel counts, so usually you need to target in a different way.
Related: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html

Comment: @jnelson I don't want the queries to work specifically for iPhones, I would like the Navbar to collapse as soon as the screen size is smaller than the 960px

Comment: I understand :-). What I am trying to say, is that the @media screen and (max-width: 960px) target will not target a iPhone, because it has more pixels. Not just iPhones, any phone with high res screens will ignore this 960px width. So I recommend playing with https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ or other links to find out what works for you

Comment: @jnelson alright, thank you I will check that out. I don't know why didn't come up with that conclusion myself, but now that I think about it, it makes total sense.

Comment: Ah wait - Konstantinos answer is actually a better approach - your media query will work then

Comment: @jnelson yes it fixed my problem, everything works just fine now, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't done this already please try to add to the  the following line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Nice idea - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag (more info here)

Comment: I just tried it, it actually fixed my problem, thanks a lot :)