# Why does my website look weird/bad on iOS, but works just as intended on every other platform/browser?

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

This is most likely an obvious answer but as I am new to web development/website building I can't wrap my head around this issue. So the thing is that I am building a landing page for a fictional store and recently started making it responsive, but I have noticed that it looks way off on my iPhone (tested on both iOS 14.8 and 15.2, both XR), while on my Mac and on a OnePlus 6 it appears just as I want it to.

I know that iOS browser are technically all using webkit so they are the same, but how do I fix it for webkit?

Android examples:

1 [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjkN8.jpg) 2. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsUjn.jpg) 3. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyS9k.jpg)

iOS examples:

1 [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nA7kP.png) 2 [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBhGh.jpg) 3 [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikskd.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087446/all-media-queries-for-iphone-13-pro-max-mini-and-older-iphones and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759046/iphone-6-and-6-plus-media-queries might give you some hints :)

Comment: I don't think we can help much from just looking at pictures. Can you post an example of code (preferably as a runnable snippet so we can easily try it for ourselves on IOS devices) which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example